# Azure Table Storage Support empty columns field at the time of insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Can Azure table support null value or empty value in the column field at the time of insert a record on the azure table?

Let take an example if I have one table with below fields

[image: Table Reference]

Where the column description is mentioned below:

1. LastModifiedOn **DateTime** with Null Value accepted
2. LastModifiedById **Guid** with Null Value Accepted
3. IsActive **bool** with NotNull
4. Description **string** with Null Value Accepted

I want to prepare the same table in the azure table but when I was created then those have a null value that columns haven't created into the azure table only those columns have a value that should be created in the Azure table. and I want both cases should be cover in my requirement must have value and null or empty columns.

Should this be achievable or not?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to your question is no. An Azure Table entity cannot have a `null` value parameter.

Essentially an entity is simply a property bag which contains one or more attributes. Either an attribute will be present or absent. It is not possible to have an attribute with null value.